# Solution for TypeError in VALID_SCOPE_NAME_REGEX in tensorflow framework

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following error when I run my code:

> File
>   "C:\Users\HP\Miniconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2902, in name_scope
>       if not _VALID_SCOPE_NAME_REGEX.match(name):
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

*Ops.py line 2902 corresponds to:*

> if not _VALID_SCOPE_NAME_REGEX.match(name):
>            raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid scope name" % name)

## I'm getting this in the following lines of code:

```
training_predictions, test_predictions = seq2seq_model(tf.reverse(inputs,[-1]), targets, keep_prob, batch_size, sequence_length, len(answerword2int),len(questionword2int), enc_embedding_size, decoding_embedding_size,rnn_size, num_layers, questionword2int)
```

---

```
 def seq2seq_model(inputs, targets, keep_prob, batch_size, sequence_length, answer_num_words, question_num_words, enc_embedding_size, decoder_embedding_size,rnn_size, num_layers, questionswords2int):

enc_embedded_input = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(inputs,answer_num_words+1, enc_embedding_size, initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(0,1))

enc_state = encoder_rnn(enc_embedded_input, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, sequence_length)

preprocessed_target = preprocess_targets(targets, questionswords2int, batch_size)

decoder_embeddings_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([question_num_words + 1,decoder_embedding_size],0,1))

decoder_embedded_input = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(decoder_embeddings_matrix,preprocessed_target)

training_predictions, test_predictions = decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input,decoder_embeddings_matrix,enc_state,question_num_words,sequence_length,rnn_size, num_layers,questionswords2int,keep_prob,batch_size)

return training_predictions, test_predictions
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: The code has been formatted.